# Where can I read about this jQuery selector / method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I saw this syntax somewhere when I needed a solution for my problem. However I don't know what it exactly means. I tried to find reference for it but couldn't find one.

Here it is:

```
var a = $('<div>', {class: "foo"});
```

Is there any official description about this in jQuery documentation?

Comment: You can read about it in the http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Comment: It's creating a `div`: "If the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML"

Answer (score 0):

read about it on jquery official doc
[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question ,that syntax is used to create your custom HTML elements in DOM.

You can also use this to create dynamic HTML elements as your requirements .Let me add an example for you

```
var a = $('<div>', {class: "foo"});
```

is a declaration that you wanna create a div which class name "foo"

if you see the  below code

```js
$('<div/>', {
    class: 'foo',
    text: 'Created Div'
    
}).appendTo('#s');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="s"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Besides You can also write the above syntax in a different way for example

var a="Created Div"

and it will also execute the same result see the example below

```js
var a="<div class='foo'>Created Div</div>"

$("#s").append(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="s"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Inspect the elements in browser you will see how it created a div
Hope It Helps.

Comment: Okay. What if I write `$({foo: 5})` ? Is it a valid jQuery statement? If yes then what does it mean?

Comment: No What you write is wrong .it doesnt mean anything.

Comment: But it doesn't give any error in console. Looks like it is valid.

Comment: Because It is Creating an object only in your console but if you write                var a=({foo:5})  and then console.log(a.foo) you will get 5

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 4 selectors in jQuery to interact with DOM elements, but mostly used 2.

```
Class: $('.className').click(handler);
id: $('#idName').click(handler);
```

Comment: Do you mind not always editing your answer to a bad formatting?